React / sass overflow attribute is not working on navbar
Here is the revised post for Stack Overflow with the formatting and code adjusted:

Title: Navbar Sliding Off-Screen Increases Left Margin Despite overflow: hidden
I'm trying to make my navbar slide off the screen to the right, but when the CSS rule right: -100%; is applied, the space on the left increases, causing layout issues as shown in this screenshot:

I've already tried using overflow: hidden on all parent elements, but it still doesn't work. Here is my React component and the relevant CSS.
React Component:
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Logo from '../img/code.svg';
import { AuthContext } from '../context/authContext';
import { MdMenu } from "react-icons/md";
import { IoClose } from "react-icons/io5";

const links = ['News', 'Tutorials', 'Resources', 'Bootcamps'];

const Navbar = () => {
  const [isMenuActive, setIsMenuActive] = useState(false);
  const { currentUser, logout } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const isAdminOrWriter = currentUser && (currentUser.role === 'admin' || currentUser.role === 'writer');

  const handleMenuClick = () => {
    setIsMenuActive(!isMenuActive);
  };

  return (
    <div className='navbar'>
      <div className='nav-container'>
        <Link to='/'>
          <div className="logo">
            <img src={Logo} alt=""/>
            <p className='logo-text'>JuanCDEV</p>
          </div>
        </Link>
        <div className={isMenuActive ? "links" : "links off"}>
          <div className="nav-links">
            {links.map((link) => (
              <NavLink end className='link' key={link} to={`/?category=${link.toLowerCase()}`}>
                <h6>{link}</h6>
              </NavLink>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div className="session">
            {currentUser && (
              <>
                <span className='session'>{currentUser.username}</span>
                <span className='session' onClick={logout}>Log out</span>
              </>
            )}
            {!currentUser && <Link className='link' to="/login">Login</Link>}
          </div>
          {isAdminOrWriter && <Link className='link' to='/write'>
            <div className='write-button'>Write</div>
          </Link>}
        </div>
        <div className="menu">
          <div className={isMenuActive ? 'burger off' : 'burger'} onClick={handleMenuClick}>
            <MdMenu />
          </div>
          <div className={isMenuActive ? 'close' : 'close off'} onClick={handleMenuClick}>
            <IoClose />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;

SCSS File:
$lightGreen: #0353a4;

@import 'sass-files/media-queries';
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap");

@keyframes move {
  0%, 49.99% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  50%, 100% {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
  }
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #222831;
  overflow-x: hidden;

  @include small-screen {
    max-width: 800px;
  }
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;

    .link {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: inherit;
    }

    h1 {
      font-size: 30px;
      color: #0353a4;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .auth_container {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      background: rgb(0, 24, 69);
      background: linear-gradient(34deg, rgba(0, 24, 69, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 49%);
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;

      .card {
        border-radius: 30px;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1));
        backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
        -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
        width: 800px;
        max-width: 100%;
        min-height: 650px;

        .form-container {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          height: 100%;
          transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;

          &.sign-in {
            left: 0;
            width: 50%;
            z-index: 10;
          }

          &.register {
            left: 0;
            width: 50%;
            opacity: 0;
            z-index: 1;
          }

          h1 {
            color: white;
          }

          form {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            gap: 20px;
            background: white;
            padding: 50px;
            width: 230px;
            min-height: 300px;
            border-radius: 3%;
            box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            margin-bottom: 40px;

            input {
              font-size: 14px;
              padding: 10px;
              border: none;
              border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
              margin-bottom: 20px;
              background-color: transparent;
            }

            input::placeholder {
              color: grey;
            }

            button {
              font-size: 14px;
              padding: 10px;
              border: none;
              background-color: #0466c8;
              color: white;
              cursor: pointer;
              border-radius: 3px;
            }

            p {
              display: flex;
              font-size: 14px;
              color: rgb(206, 14, 52);
              justify-content: center;
              align-items: center;
              height: auto;
              width: auto;
              background-color: rgba(199, 43, 74, 0.2);
              border-radius: 5px;
              margin: 10px;
              padding: 10px;
              text-align: center;
              box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            }

            span {
              font-size: 14px;
              text-align: center;

              a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #014f86;
              }
            }
          }
        }

        .toggle-container {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 50%;
          width: 60%;
          height: 100%;
          overflow: hidden;
          transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
          border-radius: 100px 0 0 100px;
          z-index: 1000;

          .toggle {
            height: 100%;
            width: 200%;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #48bfe3, #0466c8);
            position: relative;
            left: -100%;
            transform: translateX(0);
            transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
            color: white;

            .toggle-panel {
              position: absolute;
              width: 50%;
              height: 100%;
              gap: 20px;

              .login-img {
                width: 300px;
              }

              h1 {
                color: #fff;
              }

              display: flex;
              align-items: center;
              justify-content: center;
              flex-direction: column;
              text-align: center;
              transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
              top: 0;
              padding: 0 30px;
              text-align: center;
              transform: translateX(0);
            }

            .toggle-left {
              transform: translateX(-200%);
            }

            .toggle-right {
              right: 0px;
              transform: translateX(0);
            }

            .toggle-left {
              transform:

 translateX(0);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      .form-container {
        &.active {
          &.sign-in {
            transform: translateX(100%);
            opacity: 0;
            z-index: 0;
          }

          &.register {
            transform: translateX(100%);
            opacity: 1;
            z-index: 5;
            animation: move 0.6s;
          }
        }
      }

      .toggle-container {
        &.active {
          transform: translateX(-100%);
          border-radius: 0px 150px 100px 0px;

          .toggle {
            transform: translateX(50%);

            .toggle-panel {
              padding: 0;

              &.toggle-left {
                padding-left: 30px;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    .navbar {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #000;
      text-decoration: none;
      z-index: 2;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      overflow: hidden !important;

      .nav-container {
        padding: 10px 0px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        color: white;
        width: 1024px;
        overflow: hidden !important;
        isolation: isolate;

        a {
          text-decoration: none;
        }

        .logo {
          display: flex;
          gap: 10px;
          padding-left: 10px;
          overflow: hidden;

          .logo-text {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: large;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-decoration-line: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            overflow: hidden;
          }

          img {
            width: 50px;
            cursor: pointer;
            overflow: hidden;
          }

          @include medium-screen {
            padding-left: 30px;
          }
        }

        .links {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          gap: 8px;
          overflow: hidden;

          .nav-links {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            gap: 15px;

            h6 {
              font-size: 16px;
              font-weight: 300;
            }

            span {
              cursor: pointer;
            }

            a {
              &::after {
                content: "";
                height: 2px;
                width: 0%;
                background-color: #0353a4;
                display: block;
                position: relative;
                top: -34px;
                transition: width 0.4s ease;
              }

              &:hover::after {
                width: 100%;
              }
            }
          }

          .session {
            display: flex;
            gap: 15px;
            overflow: hidden;
          }

          .write-button {
            background-color: black;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            color: #fff;
            justify-content: center;
            font-weight: 300;
            border: 1px solid black;
            transition: all;
            transition-duration: 250ms;
            overflow: hidden;

            &:hover,
            &:focus {
              color: #fff;
              background-color: black;
              border: 1px solid #0353a4;
            }
          }

          @include medium-screen {
            padding-right: 30px;
          }

          @include small-screen {
            &.off {
              right: -100%;
            }

            background-color: #333;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 78px;
            right: 0;
            flex-direction: column;
          }
        }

        .menu {
          display: none;
          align-items: center;

          @include small-screen {
            display: flex;
          }

          .burger {
            display: none;

            svg {
              width: 26px;
              height: auto;
            }

            @include small-screen {
              display: block;
              padding-right: 30px;
              &.off {
                display: none;
              }
            }
          }

          .close {
            display: none;

            &.off {
              display: none;
            }

            svg {
              width: 26px;
              height: auto;
            }

            @include small-screen {
              display: block;
              padding-right: 30px;
              &.off {
                display: none;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

I've added overflow: hidden to most elements, but the issue persists. What am I missing or doing wrong?


What if you reduce the width of it to 0px?

That's not how stackoverflow works (posting 500 lines of code, a description of what it's supposed to do, and then expect the community to debug and fix it for you).
I voted "Close - needs more focus".
But I don't want to be unhelpfull either so I'll try to give you a guide that should allow you to unblock yourself by providing what I usually do in such situations.
Whenever I implemented some UI behavior where HTML, CSS, and JS must play nicely together to form some desired result, and there is a bunch of nested HTML elements and associated CSS properties that all must just be exactly right to have the desired effect and the cherry ontop that steaming pile of complexity is an animation or transition and I stormed in Leeroy Jenkins style and ended up with something that's not working but is way too complex to have any clear idea what is not working ... I build a bare-bones proof-of-concept tryout HTML document out of raw HTML, CSS, and JS - no framework, nothing that adds complexity (even if the final feature is supposed to be part of a React app).

new file "slide-in-menu-tryout.html"

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>


add some <div> elements and class="" attributes as needed
add <style> to head and fill as needed
add <script> to end of body and fill as needed
tweak as long as it takes to get it working as desired
with a clear understanding and such a blue print go back to your React app and start from a clean starting point

You might want to try animated display: grid columns for your slide-in menu.
